# A definite integral with $\exp$ and $\cos^n$

Tags: integration

I came across the following integral formula, left as an exercise, in Mark Kac's "Statistical Independence in Probability, Analysis, and Number Theory."  I've been unable to prove it and would like a little help:

$$ \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{-i(2l-n)x}\cos^{n}(x) \,dx = \frac{1}{2^n}\binom{n}{l}, $$

where $0 \le l \le n$ are integers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: use Euler's formula
$$\cos(x) = \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2}$$
expand it by the binomial formula, then evaluate the integral term by term.